# get JMenuItems through loop

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I have added all the jmenuitems in different jmenubars.My question is that how to get all the menu items in jmenubars through the loop so that I could able to remove menuItems dynamically on some basis of some condition. Please let me know how it could be possible. [image: I have added menu items like this]

Comment: You can add all menu item in one yml file, and based on condition u can hide the menuitems in java file

Comment: @Balasubramanian Thanks alot for your response but i need to loop in because i have so many menuitems as i am working on ERP having so many  menuitems . Can you please suggest me how can i loop through menubars to get all their menuItems ?

Comment: yes. u can add all menuitems in tml file and based on condition in loop for showing that menu items. share ur tried code for ref?

Comment: `how to get all the menu items in jmenubars through the loop` - you just answered your own question. "You write a loop". So read the `JMenu` API for a method to get you the total number of menu items and then write a loop to get each individual item, the API will also have a method for that.